# BadMethodCallException in Builder.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm not having much luck tying to get past the following error

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::posts()
```

The project I'm working on is a simple timeline for a social network.
Although I'm stuck when calling the following route (creating a post)

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
Route::get('home', 'TimelineController@index');
Route::post('/posts', 'PostController@create');
});
```

POST returns the 500 error I specified above. A quick search for the "unimplemented" method posts() returns:

```
Searching 5094 files for "posts()"

C:\Users\Administrator\Code\instyle\app\User.php:
   16      ];
   17  
   18:     public function posts()
   19      {
   20          return $this->hasMany('Instyle\Post');

    C:\Users\Administrator\Code\instyle\app\Http\Controllers    \PostController.php:
   17          ]);
   18  
   19:         $createdPost = $request->user()->posts()->create([
   20              'body' => $request->body,
   21          ]);
```

Since I'm having trouble pinpointing this error I'll happily elaborate on any file you require.
Thanks!

As stated by Khalid Dabjan I modified the function "create" to include the following line "dd($request->user());"

The result was a 200 response from the server containing a JSON with all the info relevant to the logged in user.

My Post Controller is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace Instyle\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Instyle\Http\Requests;
use Instyle\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Instyle\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
public function create(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'body' => 'required|max:600',
    ]);

    $createdPost = $request->user()->posts()->create([
        'body' => $request->body,
    ]);

    return response()->json($post->with('user')->find($createdPost->id));
}
```

}

Comment: in the create function could you try `dd($request->user());` and updating your question with the output of that.

Comment: Thanks for the input @KhalidDabjan

Comment: I think your problem is in the namespacing of the models, what is the namespace for `Post` model and `User` model?

Comment: @KhalidDabjan my namespace is simply the name of the app for both models. Editing these in any way gives me a reflection exception "class does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error myself thanks to @Khalid Dabjan poking in my code.
I was using the wrong file for my Users model, for some reason I was using two and the one that didn't have the posts() method was being applied.
[image] 
I have no idea why I was using two User.php files but that is best left aside for another question since the answer to this question is now clear:
I wasn't implementing the fuction posts() on the correct model, that's why I was getting a "function does not exist" error.

Comment: Here's aditional information that may interest anybody that runs in to any similar error https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#defining-models